# getting error Property '...' does not exist on type 'typeof "...."'

Tags: node.js, typescript, gulp

I am developing an app in node js using typescript and use the gulp transpiler in commonjs mode.

I have wrote a homeController.ts as:

```
let homeController={
     getIndex:(req,res)=>{
        res.send('Hello world'); //Compiles the file named "index" in the views directory (`/views`) using the view engine (Jade).
    },
}
export default homeController;
```

and i have a separate route file for routing as route.ts

```
import  home  =require('../controller/homeController');
import express = require('express');

let router = express.Router();

router.get('/',home.getIndex);

module.exports = router;
```

and import it in server file as

```
import  routes = require('./routes/route');
```

and route it as

```
app.use('/api', routes);
```

but when gulp compile these file it give the error

[image]

please correct me if i'm doing any mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your homeController.ts file exports an object with the shape `{ default: { getIndex: ... } }`. It does not have a top-level `getIndex` property.

You probably want to use `export = homeController` instead of `export default homeController`. They are not equivalent.

Comment: this help to solve the route.ts file error but i still have server.ts file error